# Typed numpy ndarray with Cython Extension Types

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I want to use an Cython Extension type as a numpy 'dtype' in a function signature.

For example, suppose I have:

```
cdef class MyType:
    int counter
    int[:] someArray
    float value
```

Then for efficient indexing, in my function signature I want to to declare:

```
def my_function(np.ndarray[MyType, ndim=1] my_types):
    for my_type in my_types:
       pass
```

However, I get the compilation error `dtype must be "object", numeric type or a struct`. As I understand it, Cython extension types *are* actually C structs — so is it possible to make this work?

Comment: There are some pretty fundamental problems with trying to make that fit into Python's memory management and type system.

Comment: "As I understand it, Cython extension types are actually C structs" - only so far as all other Python types are actually C structs.

Comment: A numpy array, in Python or cython, can only have pointers to objects stored elsewhere, or a fixed number of bytes per item (the struct dtype).  Is the `someArray` in your class fixed in size, or open?

Comment: I can imagine mapping a numpy dtype like `dt = np.dtype((void, 10))` onto a C-struct of the same size.  Then you can use all the numpy, and cython memory view mechanism to index such an array, while using your own `c` and extension-type code to access the components of each `n` byte block.